# How to tell a Fragment to inflate a View after its already added without a View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I have the following situation:

I'm adding a Fragment without a UI to do some background works

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(btFragment, "btFragmentAsBackgroundWorker");
ft.commit();
```

After it is added, it is not shown to the user. So it works perfectly fine. But at one point the user can access that Fragment to change some things, so I have to show it with an UI.

In order to show it I use it like this

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.remove(menuFragment).show(btFragment);
 ft.commit();
```

But obviously there is no View inflated. How can I achieve this?

I tried this, but I get an error

```
ft.remove(menuFragment).add(R.id.fragmentMenu, btFragment);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: BTFragment{5c942bb #1 id=0x7f0c0072 btFragmentAsBackgroundWorker}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code as follow....

to add fragment without view

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(btFragment, "btFragmentAsBackgroundWorker");
ft.commit();
```

to add view

```
 ft.replace(R.id.fragmentMenu,btFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the btFragment, because I have active Threads working there. If I remove it, they all get destroyed.

Comment: I tried that aswell, it is essentially the same as `remove().add()` and it doesn't work because the Fragment is already added

Answer (score 0):

Creating a view is part of the fragment life cycle and can't really be deferred.  I would suggest that you at least create an empty container `ViewGroup` in `onCreateView()`.  Then you can add views to the container later.

Alternatively, consider creating a view with visibility `GONE` and setting it to `VISIBLE` when you are ready to display a UI.

Answer (score 0):

> To add a fragment without a UI, add the fragment from the activity
>   using add(Fragment, String) (supplying a unique string "tag" for the
>   fragment, rather than a view ID). This adds the fragment, but, because
>   it's not associated with a view in the activity layout, it does not
>   receive a call to onCreateView(). So you don't need to implement that
>   method.
>
> Supplying a string tag for the fragment isn't strictly for non-UI
>   fragments—you can also supply string tags to fragments that do have a
>   UI—but if the fragment does not have a UI, then the string tag is the
>   only way to identify it. If you want to get the fragment from the
>   activity later, you need to use findFragmentByTag().